# Hide 'no results found' until form clicked

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a db query in WordPress that works Okay, but the echo no results found is visible on page load.

Is there a way of not showing the 'no results found' message until the form submit button is clicked?

Here is my code:

```
if(empty($results)) { 
     echo "<p>no results found</p>"; 
} else { 
     foreach($results as $r) { 
         echo "<ul><li><p><a href=\"?$r->id\">$r->fb_name</a> - $r->tel</p></li></ul>";
     }
}
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: check form is submit or not

Comment: how its possible , without submit how your query execute? i think the problem in submitting

Comment: Sorry User1234 has the correct answer :)

Comment: yes you miss button name . keep coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that `form` is submitted or not

```
if(empty($results)  && isset($_POST['submit']))
```

here `submit` is the name of your `submit button`

Comment: This worked when I added name="submit" to my button!  Thank You!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
if(empty($results) && isset($_POST["submit"]))
```

to check if the form has been submitted